# Check counter then append jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my view I have list of items and when I clicked the edit button all the information of that item is listed. I have "Add Item" button in my bottom part of my table

Example: I clicked the edit button there will be a delete button

```
Name      Qty   Price
Apple      1    50     Delete Button
Mango      2    100    Delete Button

Add Item Button
```

When I click the "Add Item" it will add new item with delete button. So what I want now is in the first row, the delete button will not be display.

```
Name      Qty   Price
Apple      1    50     
Mango      2    100    Delete Button

Add Item Button
```

Question: How can I prevent showing the delete button in my first row?

NOTE: What I have right now is, it gives me an undefined

**Js**

```
// click function
.....
var counter=0;
$('tbody#my-items tr').each(function(key, value){
counter++
....
if(counter !=  1){
var delete_row;
delete_row += '<button class="btn btn-danger delete-row" data-counter="delete-row-'+counter+'"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>';}
$('tbody#my-items').append(''
 ......
 '<tr>'
  +'<td>'
    +delete_row
  +'</td>'
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: Use something like https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://codepen.io/ to create a working example, it'll be easier to help you

Comment: yeah @HereticMonkey said it better than me